# playframework1.2 has some Chinese garbled

Tags: playframework

when  i  use the          &{'unit'}   , and   the  "unit=元" is in  the file of  messages.zh_CN ,but i get the  garbled.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that your messages.zh_CN file has utf-8 encoding. I had the very same problem with Russian messages becuase the file had wrong encoding. In intellij IDEA, for example, you can fix it from menu -> setting -> file encodings.

Comment: My messages.zh_CN file has utf-8 encoding,some Chinese are garbled,others are ok.

Comment: I have no idea, sorry. For me utf-8 is enough

Comment: And the Play 1.1.1 hasn't the problem,I just "play run" my Previous Program in Play1.2

Comment: I found similar problem description here: http://play.lighthouseapp.com/projects/57987-play-framework/tickets/346

Answer (score 2):

As Tim pointed out, this is a known issue, related to http://play.lighthouseapp.com/projects/57987-play-framework/tickets/710-messages-files-read-broken-when-they-contain-certain-character - this should be fixed soon in a 1.2.1 release.

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem with russian language, but I'm pretty sure, that my files were utf-8 encoded (in vim I use set fenc, set enc) it says utf-8
I don't use some messages though (